# Using Register-PSRepository to add an org-scoped feed using nuget/v3 endpoint does not work

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I am following Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops#connect-to-feed-as-a-powershell-repository. When I run Register-PSRepository it fails with

```
$patToken = "XXXXcj2s3q" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credsAzureDevopsServices = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("XXXX@ceridian.com", $patToken)
Register-PSRepository -SourceLocation https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/_packaging/FEED/nuget/v3 -Name DCloud 
-PublishLocation https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Ceridian-dryrun/_packaging/dayforce/nuget/v3 -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices
 Register-PSRepository : The specified Uri 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/_packaging/FEED/nuget/v3'
for parameter 'SourceLocation' is an invalid Web Uri. Please ensure that it meets the Web Uri requirements.
```

Running this command with https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/_packaging/FEED/nuget/v2 succeeds but when I am trying to run Find-Module it fails with

```
 Find-Module -Repository DCloud -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices
WARNING: Query Url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG/_packaging/FEED/nuget/v2 is invalid.
```